# How to change the text size in side the text view in android?

Tags: android, textview

I have textview inside that i want to change the text size of text in middle of the text like below

[image]

Comment: There's probably a better answer out there, but I would just separate those by different textviews with their own respective sizes

Comment: I think you solved your own problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Html.fromHtml(str)`:

```
String str="<font size =\"20\"><B>Bold</B> <br/> Then Normal Text<br/>
                         <i>Then Italic</i> </font>" +
                       "<br/> <font color=\"green\" >this is simple sentence </font>" +
                       "<br/> <font face=\"verdana\" >this is simple sentence </font>"+
                       "<br/><br/><br/><br/><a>this is simple sentence</a>";
Spanned strHtml= Html.fromHtml(str);

TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
tv.setText(strHtml);
```

Or you can use [SpannableString](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html).

Comment: Thanks Padma Kumar.Really helps me

Comment: Text size didn't change at run time .

Comment: TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.widget47);
  String str="<font size =\"50px\"><B>Bold</B> <br/> Then Normal Text<br/> <i>Then Italic</i> </font>" +
          "<br/> <font color=\"green\" >this is simple sentence </font>" +
          "<br/> <font size=\"32px\" >this is simple sentence </font>"+
          "<br/><br/><br/><br/><a>this is simple sentence</a>";
   Spanned strHtml= Html.fromHtml(str);

    tv.setText(strHtml);

Answer (score 4):

```
String text1 = "Hi";
String text2 = "there";

SpannableString span1 = new SpannableString(text1);
span1.setSpan(new AbsoluteSizeSpan(textSize1), 0, text1.length(), SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

SpannableString span2 = new SpannableString(text2);
span2.setSpan(new AbsoluteSizeSpan(textSize2), 0, text2.length(), SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

// let's put both spans together with a separator and all
CharSequence finalText = TextUtils.concat(span1, " ", span2);
```