# how to change the color of special words in textView?

Tags: android, textview

I create a textView with the String in main.xml file. I want to change the color of some words when press the button.  eg. when press the button, the color of all the word "to" in the string is change to red. How can I do this? 
Assume I have a button and the onClickListener.what to do in the OnClickListeren?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8913454/1012284

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like below for this :

```
actualStringToDisplay="font COLOR=\"RED\"><b>"+yourString</b></font>";  
 textDisplayedBottom.setText(Html.fromHtml(actualStringToDisplay));
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
....
Spannable span = new SpannableString("SOME STRING...");        
span.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, 4, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
yourTextView.setText(span);
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='red'>colored text</font>other text",
                   TextView.BufferType.SPANNABBLE);
```